# Radio checked and addeventlistener is not working

Tags: javascript

I am using one js file for two html page 
Here is my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css"> -->
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  
    
</head>
<body>

   <div id="salestable">
        <label for="Type">Today</label>
        <input type="radio" id="day" name="months" value="Today" checked>
        <label for="Type">Peroid</label>
        <input type="radio" id="range-period" name="months" value="Peroid" onchange="getperiod()">
        
         <input type="date" name="Date" id="startdate" >
        <input type="date" name="Date" id="end-date"  >
    </div>


  <script src="../db.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The `today` radio button is checked by default 
i want to add onchange event listner to first input date `id = startdate` if the today radio button is checked

Here is the code i tried in `db.js`

```
if(document.getElementById('day').checked){
    // get date element 
   const day = document.getElementById('startdate');
   day.addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log('hi); 
   });
}
```

I also tried inside the script tag in html but the code does not work 
and another doubt is 
if i add the eventlistener to date in `script` tag in html
like this

```
  <script>
  
   
    const day = document.getElementById('startdate');
    day.addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log('hi'); 
    });
  

  </script>
```

The code is working fine and logging as hi 
but when I add the same code in `db.js` file the code does not work

Any one help to solve

Comment: In the db.js file did you add the code with <script> tag or without it?

Comment: without script tag

Comment: If radio "Today" is checked by default, what's the point of adding event listener only if it's checked? Perhaps you should move the checking to inside of event listener instead. Also, did you check for any error messages in console?

Comment: thank you for this added a if condition inside onchange function

Answer (score 2):

In your `db.js` file you forgot `'` in `console.log('hi);`. You have to change it with `console.log('hi');`

I ran your code as an inline script and it works!

```js
   
    const day = document.getElementById('startdate');
    day.addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log('hi'); 
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css"> -->
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  
    
</head>
<body>

   <div id="salestable">
        <label for="Type">Today</label>
        <input type="radio" id="day" name="months" value="Today" checked>
        <label for="Type">Peroid</label>
        <input type="radio" id="range-period" name="months" value="Peroid" onchange="getperiod()">
        
         <input type="date" name="Date" id="startdate" >
        <input type="date" name="Date" id="end-date"  >
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i above mention that eventlistener is working well in inline but i want to work on radio button checked condition in inline or db.js file

Comment: Ok I've checked the `document.getElementById('day').checked` in my inline script code

Comment: In my computer I also tried with db.js and still everything was good. check to see your db.js are loaded correctly?

Comment: i added the db.js above body closing tag only and in this html the db is correctly loaded but i did not get why event listener are not working i think there is already four listeners for another html page in db.js so only the event listener is not working